# Facebook iOS api sets permissions to optional?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm trying to ask the users of my app to sign in with Facebook but I don't want them to be able to log in unless they allow certain permissions. How do I do this?

```
NSArray *permissions =  [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"publish_stream", @"friends_birthday", nil];
[facebook authorize:permissions];
```

With this code the user is able to select which permissions they want to grant the application. I want to set publish_stream as a required permission and if the user does not accept this they can't sign in with Facebook. Is this possible with the Facebook iOS API?

[image]

Comment: Wow, your suggestion is really user-unfriendly.  Why should I trust you to post on my behalf?

Comment: The publish_stream is just an example, my question is whether it's possible to set certain permissions to required instead of optional. I'm pretty sure I've seen it done on some websites but for the life of me I can't remember which

Answer (score 0):

I think this is up to the user to allow/disallow a permission. You cannot force it onto the user.

What you can do is the following-

On successfully coming back to your app on authentication, Check the permissions user has selected and then request for remaining permissions again. It won't still force the user but yes will help him realize **WHY** you need that permission. Hope that helps.